# Get the full name of a referenced type without loading its assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a .Net project where I'm given an assembly (`*.dll`), and I have to list out the contained types and their members.  However, I'm not given the assembly's references.

Suppose I'm given `A.dll` which has a type in it:

```cs
public class TypeInA : IInterfaceInB
{
    ...
}
```

Since I'm not given B, I get a `FileNotFoundException` when I try to call

```cs
typeof(TypeInA).GetInterfaces()
```

because it can't find `B.dll`.

I don't need the details about `IInterfaceInB`, just its namespace-qualified name.  Is there a way I can get this without having to load `B.dll`?

#### More context

I'm following the [`MetadataLoadContext` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/inspect-contents-using-metadataloadcontext) to load `A.dll` and enumerate its types:

```cs
var runtimeAssemblies = Directory.GetFiles(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "*.dll");
var paths = new List<string>(runtimeAssemblies) {path};
var resolver = new PathAssemblyResolver(paths);
using var context = new MetadataLoadContext(resolver);

var assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
```

Comment: You want to find out what's in the cupboard, but you don't want to open the cupboard. You need to rethink your problem. If you really need to do this, and i am not sure why. Store it in a metadata file, or parse the IL

Comment: `TypeInA` already has a reference to `IInterfaceInB`.  I just want to know its name.  What does the reference look like?  Does it not contain the type name?

Comment: I am a little confused, So you have an assembly that refences another assembly that doesn't exist, and you are just trying to find the fully qualified name of the type that lives in the assembly that you don't have?

Comment: Not necessarily "doesn't exist" just "don't have," but yes.

Comment: `typeof(TypeInA).Name` doesn't work ?

Comment: I can get the name of `TypeInA`, but I need the name of `IInterfaceInB`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As provided by the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/inspect-contents-using-metadataloadcontext) you posted as well

> This collection, besides assemblies you want to inspect directly, should also include all needed dependencies. For example, to read the custom attribute located in an external assembly, you should include that assembly or an exception will be thrown.

Since you do not have `B.dll`, I think it is normal that it throws an exception the moment you try to access any information in that assembly.

However, when I used ildasm.exe on A.dll, I could easily see the implemented interface(s)'s name(s). So It should be possible at least to get the names.

[image: It is possible!!!]

There is this decompiling library called [`dnlib`](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib), which I use occasionally. Here is a sample code where you can read A.dll without having B.dll and moreover get Types' implemented interfaces FullName.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using dnlib.DotNet;
......
......
private static void Main(string[] args) {
    // You need a module context in order to load an assembly
    var moduleContext = ModuleDef.CreateModuleContext();
    // This is the loaded module, please take note that it not loaded into your Domain
    var loadedModule = ModuleDefMD.Load(@"A.dll", moduleContext);
    var classes = loadedModule
        .GetTypes() //You want types in this assembly
         // I think you need classes, (structs too maybe?)
         // But you do not need the Module
        .Where(t=>t.IsClass && t.IsGlobalModuleType == false);

    foreach (var typeDef in classes) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{typeDef.FullName} implements:");
        foreach (var typeDefInterface in typeDef.Interfaces) {
            Console.WriteLine($"  {typeDefInterface.Interface.FullName}");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```